# How can i cancel the user form with button in SAP B1?

Tags: c#, sapb1

[image: Its my form]

I want to cancel the form (close the form) when click to "Vazgeç" button.

How can i do this, I am using C#

Answer (score 0):

Just SAPForm.Close();
SAPForm is SAPbouiCOM.IForm object